# fade and text img when mouseover

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS, I have found out how to fade when mouseover, but when I mouseover, how can I add in text too? Here is my HTML and CSS:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="showTeams">
    <p>Please, select a team you'd like to view:</p>
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="tZ"> <a href="#">

                    <img id="tz" src="../images/teamZeus-pic.png" class="hover item-fade" alt="team Zeus" title="team Zeus"/>

                </a>

                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="zC"> <a href="#">

                    <img src="../images/zeusCreations-pic.png" class="hover item-fade" alt="zeus Creations" title="zeus Creations"/>

                </a>

                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.tZ {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#000;
}
.zC {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#000;
}
.item-fade {
    vertical-align:top;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.hover:hover {
    opacity:0.2;
}
```

I want text to come in at the same speed as the background fade. Thanks guys

Comment: What do you mean by "add text too"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you want, but I tryed something so you can take a look to this:

```
<div class="showTeams">
    <p>Please, select a team you'd like to view:</p>
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="tZ"> <a href="#">

                    <img id="tz" src="../images/teamZeus-pic.png" class="hover item-fade" alt="team Zeus" title="team Zeus"/>

                </a>

<div id="hover-content">
        Text shows only on mouseover
</div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="zC"> <a href="#">

                    <img src="../images/zeusCreations-pic.png" class="hover item-fade" alt="zeus Creations" title="zeus Creations"/>

                </a>

                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tZ {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#000;
}
.zC {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#000;
}
.item-fade {
    vertical-align:top;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.hover:hover {
    opacity:0.2;
}

#hover-content {
    color: white;
    display:block;
}
.tZ:hover #hover-content {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here are two way to perform this with [css](http://jsfiddle.net/gjj8rthj/4/) (jsfiddle setup for css) and [jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/gjj8rthj/3/) (jsfiddle setup for jquery). youi can use any way to perform

with css you need to add text in th like

```
<h2 class="heading">This is heading</h2>
```

and css will

```
    h2.heading {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 101px;
  color: #fff;
    opacity:0;
  margin-left: 99px;
}
th:hover .heading
{
 opacity:1;   
}
```

with jquery

add this style

```
h2.heading {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 101px;
  color: #fff;
    display:none;
  margin-left: 99px;
}
```

and script

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
      $('th').hover(function()

                    {
                    $(this).find('.heading').show();

                    })

    })
```